# code for google app engine using maven

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, maven

I have been following the steps to create a google app engine app using maven. https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/getstarted/backend/auth
I am on the step to deploy using `mvn appengine:update` but once it gets to the point where it says `Updating Google App Engine Application` there is a prompt that says `Please enter code:`. I can not find any documentation on what this code is supposed to be. I can deploy it to the devserver and use localhost:8080 just fine. Does anyone know what this code is supposed to be?

Answer (score 3):

I found the code. I did not realize that Firefox was being opened in the background. From Firefox I was supposed to accept the permissions and it would then supply the code.